# Create Action for LLD discovered trigger in Zabbix

Tags: alert, zabbix

### What I'm trying to achieve:

I want to create alerts for some discovered items in Zabbix.

### What I did so far:

I created a custom LLD script and configuration for Zabbix that generates both items and triggers and then tried to create an action to report when anything goes wrong.

### What went wrong?

After going to `Configuration` → `Actions` →Selecting the desired trigger, Under `New condition` I'm selecting `Trigger` & `=` → `Select`.

Now I'm looking at the window opened, the `Template` is correct but there are no triggers.

Comment: Which version of Zabbix? Note that it is not suggested to configure things this way, as limiting actions to specific triggers is hard to maintain, and LLD-created triggers could go away automatically at any time, breaking your configuration.

Comment: 3.4.8, I understand but how can I tell if they failed? and if I can't tell if they failed, what is the purpose of these items?

Comment: I strongly suggest you not to link actions to triggers: it's possible but as @Richlv pointed out it's not a good idea. You could use tags instead: for instance, if Severity=High and Tag="network related issue" then <do something>

Comment: That sounds better because otherwise there's no point using LLD in the first place.

Comment: You haven't mentioned the reason why you want to limit the action to individual triggers. Usually people have less specific conditions, limiting alerts to host groups, trigger severities and such. Having said that, I'd still expect it to work. Given that this works in pre-4.0, consider reporting a bug.

Comment: If there was an Action Prototype I could have avoided that. It's also an option, I'll try that, thanks.